# problem while installing app on iphone which is created using xcode4

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode4

hii every one

i have created one sample project(hello world) in xcode4 but i am unable to install it on iphone(ios 3.1.3)
even though i have selected deployment target 3.1.3(code signing is all proper)

i am getting followin in console while installing
2011-04-13 13:01:37.868 prjTest[244:207] *** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119cd0
2011-04-13 13:01:37.885 prjTest[244:207]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119cd0'
2011-04-13 13:01:37.902 prjTest[244:207] Stack: (
    843263261,
    825818644,
    843267069,
    842763033,
    842725440,
    9545,
    843742792,
    843741800,
    844074496,
    844072508,
    844071060,
    860907492,
    843011371,
    843009055,
    843738120,
    843731504,
    9401,
    9324
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: I also have this problem and I don't have setRootViewController anywhere in my code. Instead, I use addSubView. But, I keep getting this error with SDK 4.3 & Deployment Target 3.1.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] was added in version 4.0 so you cannot use that in 3.1.3. Instead you can use addSubView:

Comment: ya it worked fine,thanks for ur reply, i have one more doubt,will this modified code(after replacing setRootViewController by addSubView )run on ios4 & heigher version devices?

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do is replace:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
```

with

```
[self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
```

There are a couple of ways to check for the system version on the device. I've read elsewhere that Apple does not make this particularly easy as they are focused on the latest and greatest version, so there's no canonical method although many developers have devised their own solutions.

One of the more concise I've come across is:

```
if( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"4.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending )
     [self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
else
     self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
```